# Can I integrate facebook plugins in J2EE?

Tags: facebook, jakarta-ee

I visited the Facebook's developer's page and it mostly contains plugins which can easily integrate with PHP. So are their any plugins which I could use them for building my J2EE application? Will I be having the same functionality with J2EE plugins as with the PHP plugins?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) project which will you give you same possibilities like the PHP API. Also note that you need to have `spring-web` on the classpath.